# Is there a way to every tag on Tumblr different color?

Tags: tumblr

So, I wanted to make three colors as tags background on my Tumblr theme, but if I multiply

```
<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
```

I just get more tags.

I wanted first tag background to be red, second to be blue, third to be green, then fourth to be red again, and so on, and so on...
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style the page content with [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets). Usually you'd use `class` or `id` selectors to style each tag differently. But because the tags at Tumblr won't have unique classes/IDs, you can make use of the pseudo-class `nth-child`. You can find the specification there: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo (contains some examples, too).

Related blog post at css-tricks.com: [How nth-child Works](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

---

<del>You could also edit your theme and add classes to your tags. See the question [Using different styles for categories in tumblr?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10183010/1591669) and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10190328/1591669) that explains it.</del> Ah no, this adds the classes to the container of the whole post. So you could style a post differently if it is tagged with a certain tag. But that is not what you want. You could probably add the variable [`{Tag}`](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#tags) (which would be the tag name) to the markup of the tag, though. With this method you'd have to define which tags should get which color manually, which might not be what you want.

Comment: I honestly don't understand this... Don't understand the first suggestion. Or at least how to create it. I can see maybe how to do the CSS part, but I don't know how to put it in use in HTML.
Second one is definitely not what I want right now.

Comment: I actually succeeded in making this work... At least in preview. `.Tagz :nth-child(3n-2) {background-color: {color: Tag 1 Background};}
.Tagz :nth-child(3n-1) {background-color: {color: Tag 2 Background};}
.Tagz :nth-child(4n-1) {background-color: {color: Tag 3 Background};}`
When I save and open the page it doesn't work, but thank you nonetheless! :)