# Set a different style for each tag on a tumblr theme

Tags: html, css, tags, themes, tumblr

I'm coding a tumblr theme and I want the posts to display featured tags (each with a different background style)

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhQyX.jpg

I've got half of it, thanks to this answer: [Using different styles for categories in tumblr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183010/using-different-styles-for-categories-in-tumblr)

When a single tag is displayed, the code works perfectly. Each post has a different tag with a different background color, but when 2 or more tags are displayed on the same post, the style affects all of them, making them have the same background.

This is how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEQ9E.jpg

My code:

CSS

```
#tags {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 14px 14px 14px;
}

#tags a {
    background-color:;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 6px 3px 6px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

div.featured #tags a {
   background-color: #[custom green];
}

div.news #tags a {
   background-color: #[custom blue];
}
```

HTML

```
{block:Posts}
    <div class="post {TagsAsClasses}">
     Post Content...

{block:HasTags}
    <div id="tags">
      {block:Tags}
         <a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
      {/block:Tags}
    </div>
{/block:HasTags}

    </div>
{/block:Posts}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different style per tagged page on Tumblr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24700958/different-style-per-tagged-page-on-tumblr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of your implementation is wrong. When you apply a type selector, it affects all of the elements with that type.

So assume that you have 2 tags in your `tags` div, each is an `a` element. Using `#tags a` selector will give you all of these 2 elements. That's why all of your tags are having the same colour.

I think you should change your HTML code at first because you can't use different selectors with each tag if your code will be like that.

Try changing this line and add the tag name as a class to the element:

```
<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>
```

To:

```
<a href="{TagURL}" class="{Tag}">{Tag}</a>
```

So in your css, if you use the class selector, you'll get to change only that tag.

```
#tags a.{Tag} {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Which means the output HTML and CSS must be like:
HTML

```
<div id="tags">
    <a href="tags-comics" class="comics">comics</a>
    <a href="tags-cats" class="cats">cats</a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#tags a.comics {
    background-color: red;
}
#tags a.cats {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

However, this implementation is not a prototype because you can't actually determine what tags the user will define. You should try to set classes like tag-1, tag-2, tag-3 etc.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This worked like a charm! and the user will be able to set 6 featured tags to display on the index page so this works for me.

Comment: Might want to use `{URLSafeTag}` for classes. I would think certain characters (e.g. a space) would make this act weird otherwise. You wouldn't need to ask them to put dashes in for the spaces in the user input either. I'm not entirely sure what `URLEncoded` would do for a user entered variable, but if that doesn't work, you could swap the spaces for dashes using Javascript. I'm going to play with this later on my sandbox blog and let you know the outcome.